# Can this expression be evaluated for odd $n>1$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, complex-numbers

I suppose $n$ is an odd natural number greater $1$ and e.g. squarefree.
Now I try to evaluate/simplify this expression where $\mu(m)$ is the Möbius function :
$$\prod_{d|n,\ d\equiv1\mod4}(-1)^{\frac{d-1}{4}\mu(\frac{n}{d})}\prod_{d|n,\ d\equiv 3\mod 4}(-1)^{\frac{d-3}{4}\mu(\frac{n}{d})}$$
I tried to extract $$(-1)^{\frac{\phi(n)}{4}}$$
in an obvious way but then the factor
$$\prod_{d|n,\ d\equiv1\mod4}(-1)^{\frac{1}{4}\mu(\frac{n}{d})}\prod_{d|n,\ d\equiv 3\mod 4}(-1)^{\frac{3}{4}\mu(\frac{n}{d})}$$
remains to be calculated which perhaps has values 1,-1,i,-i (?).

Comment: Is the $\mu(\frac{n}{d})$ meant to be in the exponent?

Comment: Yes. I already multiplied the exponents.

Comment: Suppose $\frac{d-1}{4}=3$ and suppose $\mu=-1$. Without the Mobius you have $(-1)^3$. With it you have $(-1)^{-3}=(-1)^{3}$. The same is true if $\mu=1$. It only makes a difference if $\mu=0$, but you are assuming $n$ is square free. Are you sure it is not meant to be $(-1)^k\mu$, where $k=\frac{d-1}{4}$?

Comment: No. The $\mu(\frac{n}{d})$ are in the exponent.

Comment: Your remark seems interesting to me. If it means I could simply ignore the $\mu$ factor then I perhaps can sum over all divisors of $n$ to handle the $d$ part. Wasnt there a formula for the sum of all divisors of $n$ ?